# How to set identity_insert ON/OFF with LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

It throw's error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when **IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF**". So any can suggest me what i have done mistake.

```
   public async Task<int> InsertEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails value){
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Startup.ConnectionString);
        try
          {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee ON");
            command.Connection = conn;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertEmployeeDetails(value);
          }
           catch(Exception e)
            {
              throw e;
            }
            finally
             {
               SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT Employee OFF");
               comm.Connection = conn;
               comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
               conn.Close();
              }
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   }

public void InsertEmployeeDetails(EmployeeDetails value){
    EmployeeDetails employeeDetails=new EmployeeDetails();
    employeeDetails.Name=value.Name;
    employeeDetails.Description=value.Description;
    employeeDetails.Designation=value.Designation;
    _context.Employee.Add(employeeDetails);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What does "it" refer to?

Comment: You got to an ADO.NET call turning the identity insert ON/OFF and a separate EF context doing the Entity Insert. Note that Identity insert command is Session dependent. try this: https://entityframework.net/identity-insert

Comment: It is not a good practice to execute statements other than DDL/DML from code. Better approach is to wrap your query (including turning identity insert on/off) in a stored procedure and call it from code.

Comment: Making db calls in a `finally` block makes me uncomfortable too; what happens if the code there raises an exception; is your outer block wrapped in a try-finally too.